# Trying to update iPad 2 to iOS 6

Tags: itunes, ios, upgrade

I tried updating my iPad to iOS 6.  I plugged the iPad into my computer and it showed that is was backing up, however the update never showed up on iPad.  What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

For updating a device using iTunes, you must, first, ensure that you're using the latests iTunes Version. Then just:

1. Connect your device the computer.
2. Select your device when it appears in iTunes under *Devices*.
3. Click **Check for Update** in the Summary pane.
4. If an update is available, iTunes prompts you to download and install the update.